I am not sure what happens if there result give more than one result back
this is Code in php.
i am doing 2 queries. The main Question is, what happens if the first query brings more than one result?
I am not sure how to solve this Problem. Would like to know some ideas.
$vorname = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['schauspielerVorname'] . '%'));
    $nachname = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['schauspielerNachname'] . '%'));
    
    $schauspielerQuery = "SELECT Vorname, Nachname, id FROM schauspieler WHERE Vorname LIKE '$vorname' AND Nachname LIKE '$nachname'";
    $schauspielerResult = $mysqli->query($schauspielerQuery);

    if ($schauspielerResult && $schauspielerResult->num_rows > 0) {
        $schauspieler = $schauspielerResult->fetch_assoc();
        echo "<p>Schauspieler <b>".$schauspieler['Vorname']." ".$schauspieler['Nachname']."</b> gefunden.</p>";
    
        $filmeQuery = "SELECT filme.Titel, produktionsfirma.Bezeichnung 
            FROM filme 
            JOIN schauspieler_has_filme ON schauspieler_has_filme.Filme_Song_ID = filme.Song_ID 
            JOIN produktionsfirma ON filme.Produktionsfirma_ID = produktionsfirma.Produktionsfirma_ID 
            WHERE schauspieler_has_filme.Schauspieler_id = ".$schauspieler['id'];
        $filmeResult = $mysqli->query($filmeQuery);

        if ($filmeResult && $filmeResult->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($film = $filmeResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "Filmtitel: <b>".$film['Titel']."</b> - Studio: <b>".$film['Bezeichnung']."</b><br />";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Der Schauspieler wirkte in keinen Filmen mit.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Schauspieler nicht gefunden.";
    }

